# UIScrollView + PageControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have a view controller with outlets of scrollview (initial size: 390, 170) and page control. I need it to display an image per page from my array. But i have unexpected result (see image below).[image]

[image]

Images are not full-width and after 2nd page scrollView ends.

Here is code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Put the names of our image files in our array.
    imageArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"header1.jpg", @"header2.jpg", @"header3.jpg", nil];
    [self.articlesPageControll setNumberOfPages:imageArray.count];
    for (int i = 0; i < [imageArray count]; i++) {
        //We'll create an imageView object in every 'page' of our scrollView.
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = 390 * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.articlesScrollView.frame.size;

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        [self.articlesScrollView addSubview:imageView];
    }
    //Set the content size of our scrollview according to the total width of our imageView objects.
    self.articlesScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.articlesScrollView.frame.size.width * [imageArray count], 170);

}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
{
    // Update the page when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.articlesScrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((self.articlesScrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    self.articlesPageControll.currentPage = page;
}
```

UPD: 3rd page with image actually exists, but it's impossible to scroll to this page

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution `self.articlesScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(390 * [imageArray count], 170);`